# Decode string into an array

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

I am getting below output from a string, that I want to decode into a simple array so that I could use those value to process.
web-service used below function to return response

echo(var_export($response));

Response

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'criteriaKeyResultsMap' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     '477270310' => true,
     '528726710' => false,
     '517907210' => true,
     '497709910' => true,
     '253529610' => false,
     '529845410' => true,
     '519674810' => false,
     '517587110' => false,
     '477270610' => true,
     '260901310' => false,
     '260901610' => false,
     '529845110' => true,
  )),
))
```

I am trying with json_decode() but it gives same result.

Comment: How are you getting the string? It seems like there might be another problem here preventing an easier way of accessing the data.

Comment: API used echo(var_export($response)); to return result

Answer (score 1):

The best fix will be to update your API (if you have control of the source) to use `json_encode` instead of `var_export` before it does an echo.

Parsing the output of `var_export` is possible, but a lot more complex, resource intensive and prone to breakage in the future.

Comment: I don't have control to change in API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
json_decode($your_data,true);
```

It will produce output .

Comment: $rst = json_decode($str);
print_r($rst); this gives blank result

Comment: $rst = json_decode($str,true); add true .try this one

Comment: still getting blank response